# PageLoad event is not fired when an aspx is opened through javascript of another aspx page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, events, html, pageload

I have an aspx application with 2 aspx pages. Second aspx page will get opened on click of a button in first aspx page using JavaScript. The problem is, when the second aspx page is getting opened, its Page_load event is not firing. Only when I refresh the second page, page_load event of second aspx page is fired.

Please let me know what might be the problem and what is to be done to fire the page_load event.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I guess there is no issue in page. It is issue with browser cache. Clear your browser cache before opening second page, it should work.

Comment: Thank you. Its cache problem.

Answer (score 5):

In this case (calling the aspx page from window.open()) you have to attach the Page_Load event manually in the page's OnInit event:

```
override protected void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    this.Load += new EventHandler(Page_Load);
    base.OnInit(e);
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // your code here 
}
```

reference: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=249689

Comment: I know the thread is damn old but it never hurts to help others coming here for answers.

Answer (score 0):

Are you opening the page with showModalDialog? if so, then it's the caching issue.

If so there are muliple work arounds. Some suggest to add a random number or datetime to the query string to the URL so that it does not get cached ever.

Personally, I like this way of doing it.Refer here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c4yy9w70.aspx Make sure you set it to HttpCacheability.NoCache

Comment: I am using window.open() to open the second aspx page